# How to use visual studio code >after< installing anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

If you have never installed anaconda, it seems to be rather simple. In the installation process of Anaconda, you choose to install visual studio code and that is it.

But I would like some help in my situation:

My objective: I want to use visual studio code with anaconda

- I have a mac with anaconda 1.5.1 installed.
- I installed visual studio code.
- I updated anaconda (from the terminal) now it is 1.6.9

From there, I don't know how to proceed. 
any help please

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the correct python interpreter. When you are in a .py file, there's a blue bar in the bottom of the window (if you have the dark theme), there you can select the anaconda python interpreter.

Else you can open the command window with ctrl+p or command+p and type '>' for running vscode commands and search '> Python Interpreter'.

If you don't see anaconda there google how to add a new python interpreter to vscode

Answer (score 1):

Fer Nando's answer is correct. I made a video about the whole process after getting it figured out on make Mac and Windows 10 if you're interested. Not intended to be a promotional thing, just happen to know of a few people who were trying to pull that together. https://youtu.be/g-aS9oVY-DA